# proper replacement of QString().arg method in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, internationalization, pyqt4, qstring

When it comes to internationalization - using python2 and PyQt4 - the "proposed way" to format a translated string is using the `QString.arg()` method:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QDialog
#somewhere in a QDialog:
    self.tr("string %1 %2").arg(arg1).arg(arg2)
```

But `QString()` doesn't exist in python3-PyQt4.

So my question is, what is the best way to format any translated strings in python3? Should I use the standard python method `str.format()` or maybe there is something more suitable?

Comment: First, in PyQt4, using `QString` explicitly was definitely not the recommended way to do things; they just hadn't finished integrating native strings and QStrings yet. Notice that PyQt5 hides QString almost completely, in both 2.x and 3.x. (While we're at it, you'd almost certainly want a Unicode literal there, because otherwise you're crossing your fingers and hoping your literal is interpreted as Latin-1, not to mention doing an implicit Latin-1-to-Unicode conversion every time through this function for no good reason.)

Comment: @abarnert
Yes I might be wrong using the "proposed way" term here. I just saw Mark Summerfield use it this way in his pyqt book and thought that it would be the proper technique. Thanks for mentioning that.

Comment: Books tend to get out of date quickly. That probably _was_ a good idea 2 or 3 years ago, when staying compatible with pre-2.6 Python and pre-4.6 Qt was highly important, but my memory doesn't go back that far. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `QString::arg` method is really there as a workaround for C++'s limited string formatting support, to make sure you don't use `sprintf` with all the problems that entails (not handling placeholders that are in different orders in different languages, buffer overruns, etc.). Because Python doesn't have any such problems, there's no good reason to use it.

In fact, there's very little reason to ever use `QString` explicitly. In PyQt4, it wasn't phased out completely, but by PyQt5, it was. (Technically, PyQt4 supports "string API v2" in both Python 2.x and 3.x, but only enables it by default in 3.x; PyQt4 enables v2 by default in both, and hides the ability to switch back to v1.) See [Python Strings, Qt Strings and Unicode](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/gotchas.html#python-strings-qt-strings-and-unicode) in the documentation for some added info.

---

There is one uncommon, but major if it affects you, exception: If you're writing an app that's partly in Qt/C++ and partly in PyQt, you're going to have problems sharing I18N data when some of them are in `"string %1 %2"` format and others are in `"string {1} {2}"` format. (The first time you ship one of your file out to an outsourced translation company, they're going to get it wrong, guaranteed.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just use standard python string formatting.

`QString` is gone because it's pretty much interchangable with python's unicode strings (which are `str` in python3 and `unicode` in python2), so PyQt takes care of converting one into the other as needed.

`QString` being disabled isn't limited to python3, it's just the default there. You can get the same on python2 by doing this befor importing anything from `PyQt4`:

```
import sip
sip.setapi('QString', 2)
```

Comment: Much better coverage (or at the very least crucially complementary coverage) of the string API v2 thing; showing how to do things the v2 way in 2.x is very handy.

Comment: Thank you. I accepted abarnert's answer because it's more detailed but your answer is constructive as well.